# Meteor JS - allow/deny rules

Tags: meteor

In the example app "parties" there is a set of allow/deny rules for Parties collection.
The rule for `insert` looks like this:

```
Parties.allow({
  insert: function (userId, party) {
    return false; // no cowboy inserts -- use createParty method
  },...
```

At the same time method createParty, implements Parties.insert({....}) which is somehow not affected by the rules applied to the Parties collection.

```
.....
return Parties.insert({
      owner: this.userId,
      x: options.x,
      y: options.y,
      title: options.title,
      description: options.description,
      public: !! options.public,
      invited: [],
      rsvps: []
    });
.....
```

Could someone explain why createParty method is not affected by rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The `createParty` is in  `Meteor.methods` which is run on the server as well as the client's end by calling a `Meteor.call('createParties')` from the client. On the client it will not insert any data but the method running on the server will insert the party.

Meteors `allow` and `deny` rules control what comes from the client's end directly and don't apply for anything running on the server's end.

Comment: Tried quickly to prove Akshat statement about `Meteor.methods` is run only on server. It seems to be true:

Comment: Not always. If a method is made available to the client (e.g. not wrapped in a `Meteor.isServer`), then the client and the server will both execute the method call. You can see this simply by adding a `console.log` at the top of the `createParty` method.

Comment: Updated the answer to include that, I had no idea it also ran on the client, then I realized I always had them in Meteor.isServer blocks

Comment: A further note: Meteor needs only a single `allow` to say yes. If you have multiple `allows` not all of them will take effect. If you want to ensure a rogue insert is denied, use `deny` instead. Also if you use `deny`, you must have at least one `allow` (even if it is `return true;`.